# I would like to combine some txt files

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

Good day to everyone!

The thing is I have some txt files and I have script to put them together. Every txt file start from:

```
Export Type:                        by LAI\GCI\SAI
LAI\GCI\SAI:                        fjdfkj
HLR NUMBER:                         NA
Routing Category:                   NA
Telephone Service:                  NA
Export User Scope:                  Attached & Detached User
Task Name:                          lfl;sfd
Data Type:                          col1/col2
Begin Time of Exporting data:       2019-4-14 19:41
=================================
col1                    col2         
401885464645645         54634565754     
401884645645564         54545454564
401087465836453         54545454565     
401885645656567         53434343435
401084569498484         54342340788
401088465836453         56767686334
401439569345656         64545467558
401012993933334         55645342352
401034545566463         34353463464
```

I would like to combine just starting from col1 and col2(without names of colums), but script combine them with words in the beginning too.
Could you update this script?

```
import fileinput
import glob

file_list = glob.glob("*.txt")

with open('resultfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    input_lines = fileinput.input(file_list)
    file.writelines(input_lines)
```

and another question is I would like to get rid of 5 in the beginning of values in col2 and also  erase all rows that doesnt start from 40108/ 40188/401088e. Thank you!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and where you got stuck.

Comment: I dont know how to scip first 10 rows in every txt files that Im gonna combine. Could you update this script above, please?

Comment: Please update the question title to reflect the specific problem you are having.  It would be helpful for you to read up on [mcve].  This will help get your question in front of people who are able to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Selectively import the header by specifying the header rows.  This provides access to 'header' data in a dataframe.  From there, they may be concatenated and written back out as a csv.

Am supposing you wish to do this via Pandas, given the tags on the question.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO
import fileinput
import glob


csvdata = str("""Export Type:                        by LAI\GCI\SAI
LAI\GCI\SAI:                        fjdfkj
HLR NUMBER:                         NA
Routing Category:                   NA
Telephone Service:                  NA
Export User Scope:                  Attached & Detached User
Task Name:                          lfl;sfd
Data Type:                          col1/col2
Begin Time of Exporting data:       2019-4-14 19:41
=================================
col1                    col2
401885464645645         54634565754
401884645645564         54545454564
401087465836453         54545454565
401885645656567         53434343435
401084569498484         54342340788
401088465836453         56767686334
401439569345656         64545467558
401012993933334         55645342352
401034545566463         34353463464""")

files = ["file{}.txt".format(i) for i in range(3)]
for fn in files:
    with open(fn, "w") as f:
        f.write(csvdata)

file_list = glob.glob("file*.txt")

dfs = []
for f in file_list:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep="\s+", header=[10])
    dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df.to_csv("resultfile.txt")
```

Produces

```
,index,col1,col2
0,0,401885464645645,54634565754
1,1,401884645645564,54545454564
2,2,401087465836453,54545454565
3,3,401885645656567,53434343435
4,4,401084569498484,54342340788
5,5,401088465836453,56767686334
6,6,401439569345656,64545467558
7,7,401012993933334,55645342352
8,8,401034545566463,34353463464
9,0,401885464645645,54634565754
10,1,401884645645564,54545454564
11,2,401087465836453,54545454565
12,3,401885645656567,53434343435
...snip...
```

Comment: Hello, Rick.I guess you didnt get me. The problem I have 50-60 txt files starting like this, and col1 and col2 is long enough, I provided just an example, I just wanna create result.txt file that consists of all datas starting from col 1 and col2. I dont need the info in the beginning.

Comment: Updated my answer to provide a solution using pandas.  However, this can be easily done in Python by reading the files and skipping past the first N lines.  That is so trivial to do, I assume you wish an answer using Pandas.